# How to merge two Excel sheets

Tags: sql-server, database, excel

I have an Excel document with 10000 rows of data in two sheets, the thing is one of these sheets have the product costs, and the other has category and other information. These two are imported automatically from the sql server so I don't want to move it to Access but still I want to link the product codes so that when I merge the product tables as product name and cost on the same table, I can be sure that I'm getting the right information.

For example:

```
Code | name     | category 
------------------------------
1    | mouse    | OEM
4    | keyboard | OEM
2    | monitor  | screen

Code | cost     |  
------------------------------
1    | 123      | 
4    | 1234     | 
2    | 1232     | 
7    | 587      |
```

Let's say my two sheets have tables like these, as you can see the next one has one that doesn't exist on the other- I put it there because in reality one has a few more, preventing a perfect match. Therefore I couldn't just sort both tables to A-Z and get the costs that way- as I said there are more than 10000 products in that database and I wouldn't want to risk a slight shift of costs -with those extra entries on the other table- that would ruin the whole table.

So what would be a good solution to get the entry from another sheet and inserting it to the right row when merging? Linking two tables with field name??... checking field and trying to match it with the other sheet??... Anything at all.

Note: When I use Access I would make relationships and when I would run a query it would match them automatically... I was wondering if there's a way to do that in excel too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a vlookup? If there is a match, it will list the cost. Assuming the top is sheet1 and the other sheet2 and they both start on cell A1. You just need this in cell D2.

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:B,2,0)
```

You can then drag it down. Easiest way to fill all your 10000 rows is to hover over the bottom left corner of the cell with your cursor. It will turn from a white plus sign into a thin black one. Then simply double click.

Answer (score 2):

Just use [VLOOKUP](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx) - you can add a row to your first sheet, and find the cost based on code in the other sheet.